# How to have auto width and height for position fixed div

Tags: html, css

trying to have a auto adjust height and width, as per the content.

have set the min-height and min-width which is not working. Should not use overflow property and other positions property.

Here it is what tried:

```
Code:

.fade{
    position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.main{
    min-width:360px;
     min-height:326px;
      margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  z-index: 100001;
  /* overflow: auto; */
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.child{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[Demo Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXqWzW)

Comment: Why are you setting the restriction that you can't use ``overflow``?

Answer (score 4):

Setting both `top` and `bottom` with a percent value is causing irregularities. You have to ditched setting the `bottom` so it will have an auto height.

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here, but if you want to center the position of the `main` element with a flexible height you have to set :

```
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
```

assuming you already removed the `bottom`.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJZqJm)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the bottom property from .main class it is restricting the div from growing.

**Suggestion**

Since you div is fixed if the contents exceeded the div the user will not be able to see the content if it goes beyond the page so you may want to add a scroll if the content is overflowed.